# Camera closes in on the fixed point

Tags: xna, c#, camera, matrix

I've been trying to create a camera that is controlled by the mouse and rotates around a fixed point (read (0, 0, 0)), both vertical and horizontal. This is what I've come up with:

```
camera.Eye = Vector3.Transform(camera.Eye, Matrix.CreateRotationY(camRotYFloat));

Vector3 customAxis = new Vector3(-camera.Eye.Z, 0, camera.Eye.X);
camera.Eye = Vector3.Transform(camera.Eye, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(customAxis, camRotXFloat * 0.0001f));
```

This works quite well, except for the fact that when I 'use' the second transformation (go up and down with the mouse) the camera not only goes up and down, it also closes in on the point. It zooms in.

How do I prevent this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any thing in this snippet that will cause a zooming affect. I do, however, see a problem in the pitch rotation. `customAxis` needs to be normalized before using it as an argument in `CreateFromAxisAngle` method or the rotation amount will be incorrect. This may appear masked at the moment by your *.0001* scaling but it would be worth normalizing it to see if it is somehow playing a part in your errant zoom affect.